# Node Redis Emit/On Instead of Pub/Sub

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Is there a similar feature to WebSocket's '.emit' and '.on' with [Node Redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)? I don't like how I need to `.subscribe` and then `.publish` and listen to the response with `.on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need one connection for subscribe. 
It's not limitation of node redis but limitation of Redis itself.
As you can see in documentation  "A client subscribed to one or more channels should not issue commands, although it can subscribe and unsubscribe to and from other channels". That's why you need one connection for subscribe and other connection for all the publishes.